# How do you fully revert to HTTPS after setting up SSH for Git?

Tags: git, github, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and my source control system is Git via Github.  While the commandline is fine, I am a GUI man myself.  Previously I have had luck with using the Team Explorer pane with Git.

Recently however, our shop has said that they would like to start communicating with Github via SSH.  I configured SSH, tested it in the CLI and all was good.  It turns out that Visual Studio 2013 uses a libgit2 distribution, libgit2sharp, which does not yet support ssh.  Team Explorer, upon trying to commit responds with the following:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Reference (Error).
Failed to parse signature - malformed e-mail
```

I switched BACK to https (via the `git remote set-url` command) but this does not appear to have worked as far as Visual Studio is concerned.  I still get the above error message.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling git, and re configuring it.  I can once again access my repos through the command line and do push pull etc.  But VS still insists that my email is malformed and thus I can only conclude that it is still trying to communicate over ssh.

What else must I do to show git that I really really do want to only communicate over https?  Or, might there be something else that is confusing it?

## Edit

```
 $ git remote -v
 origin  https://github.com/REPO/PROJECT.git (fetch)
 origin  https://github.com/REPO/PROJECT.git (push)
```

Obviously the urls have been changed a bit, but they are correct in their structure.

Comment: you said you used 'git remote set-url', In this did you provide httpsurl?.

Comment: Does [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/26/customize-git-settings-in-visual-studio.aspx) help? I don't have MSVS 2013 handly so can't check myself. Also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850445.aspx) mentions repo URIs when "connecting" to a repo.

Comment: @kostix In this case it doesn't help.  The Settings page mirrors my git settings (as it pulls from those settings).  push, commit, fetch, etc all work in the command line via https, but not in VS.

Answer (score 0):

to use https you have to follow these steps

- `git remote add [shortname] [httpurl]`

  shortname - short name for your remoteurl(eg:origin, originhttp ..etc)

  httpurl - here you have to provide your remote http url
- Then you can perform push or pull operation through **shortname**

  `git push shortname master, git pull shortname master`.

Comment: I believe i have properly configured the remote urls.  See above for current return when URLS are queried.