# Git push: Insufficient permission for adding an object to repository ./objects

Tags: git, push

I tried to push my Branch to the Remote repository but it gives me unpack-objects abnormal exist: unpack error.
I have tried to change the folder permissions to 777 and user:grp to user:user then to root:root
But I still not be able to git push my master branch to repository.
May I can get help from you?

Comment: Who administers the repo? Somebody needs to give you write access to the repo

Answer (score 0):

Did you done **ssh key setup**? if you donot you can push the code in other way for this while pushing the code it will ask username and password. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263648/how-do-you-fully-revert-to-https-after-setting-up-ssh-for-git/26270920#26270920) once